# How can I widen the Styles group, to let me see the full names of Styles?

Tags: microsoft-word

The screenshot beneath proves that there's space on the right for me to widen 'Styles'.

[image]

Comment: Are you in full window mode (maximized)? If not maximized, can you drag the width wider and does that change the width of the styles dashboard?

Comment: @Karen927 Yes, in maximized. Word doesn't let me "drag the width wider".

Comment: @AnalysisJD : Time to decide.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is much wider (see screenshot below from version 2016) so this could be a glitch. Here are some things I'd try:

1. Customizing the ribbon to add/remove something and see if that fixes it.
2. Try adjusting your screen scaling to a smaller percentage in Windows display settings and then restart Word
3. See if there are any updates to install for Office
4. Reinstall / repair install Word

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can *right click* on the empty space and select **Customize the Ribbon...**
[image]

On Customize Ribbon window, Click on New Tab and Rename it as "Styles Tab".
Drag and drop Styles group from Home Tab into your new Styles Tab. Click Ok.

[image]

Now you have a new Styles Tab next to Home with widen styles.
[image]

Also you can click on tiny link coming in styles on right corner.
[image]

This will open a Styles window which you can move or size and view the style names in full.
[image]

And you can open **Style Inspector** too and view the styles formatting.
[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @harrymc It doesn't answer my question. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Negative answer : Resizing a group is not possible.
You cannot resize the ribbon, nor can you change the size of the text or the default icons.

In the Office article
[Ribbon Extensibility in Office 2010: Tab Activation and Auto-Scaling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691834%28v=office.14%29?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
you will find that a group on the ribbon is usually defined with three standard
and automatic layouts:

**Normal sized**

[image]

**Medium sized**

[image]

**Small sized**

[image]

**Single button**

[image]

The ribbon resizing policy can be further modified **by its developer**
as described in the article
[Ribbon Layout and Resizing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff701790%28v=vs.110%29?redirectedfrom=MSDN).
However, the layout to use is automatically chosen by the Office application
as function of the width of its window.
This is not under any dynamic control by the end user, nor can the user
modify the behavior as set by the developer.